# Appending text to CJuiDialog widget dynamically - Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to append text to CJuiDialog widget in Js code, In CJuiDialog content i have two buttons ,

Dialog Widget code,

```
<?php
$this->beginWidget('zii.Widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
'id'=>'update_tasks',
'options'=>array(
    'title'=>'Create Tasks',
    'autoOpen'=>false,
    'modal'=>false,
    'width'=>500,
    'height'=>300,
),
));
?>
<table  cellspacing="20">  
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::button('Add to Current Pending Tasks',array('id'=>'AddPendingTasks'));?></td><td  style = "width : 20px"></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::button('Add to Tasks',array('id'=>'AddTasks'));?></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<?php $this->endWidget();?>
```

Am opening this dialog inside JS code on another button action,

```
$('.updatetask_btn').click(function(){
    var filterid = $(this).closest('tr').find('select')[0].options[$(this).closest('tr').find('select')[0].selectedIndex].value;
    var filtername = $(this).closest('tr').find('select')[0].options[$(this).closest('tr').find('select')[0].selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('filter-id').value = filterid;
    var div = document.getElementById('update_tasks');    
    div.innerHTML =  '<label><b>'+$('#camp-name').val()+' - '+filtername+'</b></label><br>'+div.innerHTML ; 
//----- Here am appending text to the dialog dynamically ---

    $('#update_tasks').dialog('open');
});
```

Appending text blocks the two button actions in CjuiDialog content . both button onclick action not working when i append text here. Please give me any idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't fully understood your needs but I always do this way:

You need to understand and adapt to your needs.
In main view

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.min.js'] = false;
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery-ui.js'] = false;
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery-ui.min.js'] = false;

....

$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
  'id'=>'addot-dialog',
  'options'=>array(
    'title' => 'Aggiungi OT',
    'autoOpen' => false,
    'width' => 600,
    'height' => 'auto',
    'closeOnEscape' => true,
//    'close' => 'js:function() { $("table.items").find("tbody tr div.log-active").removeClass("log-active").addClass("log-inactive"); }'
  )
));
$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
?>
.....
$loadurlvendita = Yii::app()->createUrl("/otpos/otVendita/",
  array("idot" => $this->idot, "codfis" => $this->codfis));

....
```

on click here I open and fill let dialog with .load() from another view with render partial

```
CHtml::link('','',
                array('class'=>'be-icon vendita','style'=>'display:block;float:right;padding-right:6px;',
                      'onClick'=>'$("#venditaot-'.$this->idot.'").dialog("open").load(\''.$loadurlvendita.'\');'
              )).
```

controller

```
  public function actionOtVendita($idot, $codfis) {
    $proprietari = Otpos::model()->getOtposProprietari($idot);
    $this->renderPartial('vendita', array('idot' => $idot, 'codfis' => $codfis, 'proprietari' => $proprietari), false, true);
  }
```

I hoe it'll help in some way other wise clear better your needs.